# Binding to ItemsControl only works in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, observablecollection

i'm trying to Bind an ObservableCollection to an ItemsControl. I created a class called Persons with some properties. Then I created a ObservableCollection and add some Persons in there.

If I give the ItemsControl a x:Name="PersonHolder" and add the ItemsSource with PersonHolder.ItemsSource = persons then all works. But if I'm trying to add the persons with a Binding in XAML... no result.

Here is the XAML:

```
<StackPanel Background="White">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding persons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Some code from C#

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> persons { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Peter" });
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Best regards.

Comment: Where do you set the DataContext of the Control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default binding will search for property in current `DataContext`. You need to set binding context, for example by setting `DataContext` manually in code. However since `persons` does not raise [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event you need to set `DataContext` after `persons` is created otherwise UI won't be notified that property has changed

```
InitializeComponent();
persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
//after persons is created
DataContext = this;
```

without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and keeping it in XAML, you can keep single instance of *persons*

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

public ObservableCollection<Person> persons { get { return _persons; } }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();      
    persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Peter" });
}
```

and in XAML

```
<Window ... x:Name="window">
    <!-- .... -->
    <ItemsControl ... ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=persons}">
```

Comment: This works, but i dont want to make this code behind, i want to do the things per XAML. Greetz

Comment: I do. But ObservableCollection have the INotifyPropertyChanged i though. So if i change an Item there, it should change in the view. Or not?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` implement both `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` which means that if items in collection change UI will be notified but `MainWindow` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `persons` property does not raise `PropertyChanged` event so it cannot be changed. Long story short collection items can be changed but not collection itself (without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` that is)

Comment: So If i set "DataContext = this" I can create more Bindings on other Elements without changing anything or I need to set "DataContext = this" again?

Comment: when you do that `MainWindow` becomes your `DataContext` and default binding context for MainWindow children bindings.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to bind it against the control itself:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding persons,  
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

Otherwise it binds against `DataContext` property that has been set to null, right now. You could also set the `DataContext` in code behind, such as `DataContext = this`.

All binding errors are in "Output" window.

Comment: Is that code correct? Won't a `RelativeSource` binding to Self be looking for a property named `persons` on the `ItemsControl` and not the Window?

Comment: The thing with XAML works, but i dont understand so right why i need to take the RelativeSource to my Frame/Form.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest the following implementation.

Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var context = new SomeContext();
        DataContext = context;
        context.AddPerson();
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class SomeContext 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    public SomeContext()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Samuel" });
    }

    public void AddPerson()
    {
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Peter" });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Background="White">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```